# PDF Disable Anti-alias on Lines

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

I'm creating a dynamically generated PDF using FPDF.

My PDF requires many exactly horizontal/vertical lines in a grid and when rendered they are anti-aliased and look very fuzzy and unacceptable to the client. I need to remove the anti-aliasing for these(or all) lines in the doc.

I know this is possible because it's shown correctly in the adobe pdf specs itself
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf (warning: big file)
see the box in page 2 for how this should look.

How would I duplicate the box shown on this page?

-- EDIT --

```
%PDF-1.6
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/Resources 2 0 R
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Length 44>>
stream
2 J
1.00 w
20.00 821.89 m 200.00 821.89 l S

endstream
endobj
1 0 obj
<</Type /Pages
/Kids [3 0 R ]
/Count 1
/MediaBox [0 0 595.28 841.89]
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
/Font <<
>>
/XObject <<
>>
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Producer (FPDF 1.6)
/CreationDate (D:20100311190240)
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 1 0 R
/OpenAction [3 0 R /FitH null]
/PageLayout /OneColumn
>>
endobj
xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000179 00000 n 
0000000266 00000 n 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000087 00000 n 
0000000360 00000 n 
0000000435 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 7
/Root 6 0 R
/Info 5 0 R
>>
startxref
538
%%EOF
```

This is a very simple PDF file that draws a single line showing the issue I'm having. I've figured out that the trick is to add this:

```
/Type /ExtGState
/SA false
```

But I can't get it to work yet. SA is defined in 10.6.5 in the above PDF specs

Comment: I'm not seeing any grids on either page 2 or page ii. On page ii, there is a simple rectangular box, is that what you are referring to? If so, that's not quite the same as a several lined grid, nor would it be drawn the same way, either in the pdf spec or with fpdf (I would use the `Rect` method for a basic rectangle).

Comment: Anthony: Yes this is what I'm referring to. I can't just draw a simple grid. The grid I need to draw is very complicated and I need to do it using individual lines. The point I was trying to make is that what is shown is not anti-aliased.

Comment: Also, per my answer, I looked into anti-aliasing in the pdf spec and the only explicit on/off variable (`AntiAlias`) is set to false by default. And I checked the FPDF code, and there is no mention of anti-aliasing anywhere in there, so they aren't turning it on. This means that either the line draw function (in pdfs in general) is always anti-aliased with no off option, or that they call it something else, or anti-aliasing is triggered by something you are doing. If you could provide a more concrete example and a sample of your output, that would be really helpful.

Comment: It's not anti-aliased because rectangles are not anti-aliased by default. neither or lines. I'm thinking the overlap might be giving an appearance of anti-aliasing or is triggering the pdf reader to add it. Can you provide a link to a sample output?

Comment: I just created a tic-tac-toe game with fpdf and I'm not seeing any fuzziness. Again, a sample would be helpful.

Comment: Anthony: zoom way way out and you should see it. I'll post an example here soon.

Comment: It looks fine at 25%. But it is only a 4 line grid, so it might a bit easier to scale. There is an optional feature starting in the pdf 1.2 specification called "automatic stroke adjust". I can try manually adding it to your example to see if it fixes your problem, but I don't think I could tweak the fpdf code to do it, so you'd have to make a feature request. Also, are you setting your line width manually or using the default?

Comment: "automatic stroke adjust" I think we found the same thing at the same time. I want to just edit FPDF as it's a pretty simple script. I'll consider this question answered if we can get it to work on the above example.

Comment: Clarify: "I'll consider this question answered if we can get it to work on the above example." If someone can get the SA tag to do what it's supposed to do on the PDF I attached.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the code you need to add to the pdf to have the SA tag on. As far as updating the FPDF script, i'm not sure I would use the word simple. Clean and small, maybe. To add the SA rule, you would have to add a new dictionary reference to the main dictionary and then add a that graphics dictionary with reference to transfer funct. and then add the transfer function. I'm sure If I had written fpdf, that would seem pretty straight forward.

Comment: Travis, I modified the code in my answer to include some extra bit from the spec example. I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but if you already tried the original version of my code and it didn't work, try the updated version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the exact answer, but I have and idea that's a bit more than a comment...

Since you are already comfortable with the PDF specs, here's what you should try:

Figure out how fpdf is actually drawing those lines. Chances are the pdf file it outputs is compressed, so you should download [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) to uncompress it. You would do that with the command:

```
 pdftk fpdf_output.pdf output fdf_readable.pdf uncompress
```

Open up the pdf in a text editor and see if the lines are drawn the same way as the example in the PDF specs you are looking at.

If they are not, see if the method fpdf uses to draw the lines has an anti-aliasing option (in the PDF specs, I mean). If fpdf is drawing it the same way (or if their way has the option), try changing your output document (in the text editor) to have the anti-aliasing turned off. If the document won't open after editing it in the text-editor, you can run:

```
 pdftk fdf_readable.pdf output fdf_fixed.pdf
```

and it should fix any broken references or byte counts.

Then open up your tweaked pdf to see if it looks like what you are going after.

Here's the bad news: The only thing the above accomplishes is verifying that anti-aliasing is or isn't possible via the methods fpdf is using under the hood. If it is possible, there is some hope that the feature already exists or that you can make a feature request or if you are feeling really confident, you could try to extend fpdf to include some kind of `antialias("true|false")` method. If the method they use to draw the lines is not the same as the specs and doesn't have an option to turn off anti-aliasing, your best bet is probably to find an alternative pdf generator, like [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org), and seeing if they offer that feature.

### Update

Okay, I'd like to first point out that I still don't see the fuzziness. So I can't tell if this actually fixes your issue. But I did add the Automatic Stroke Adjustment rule to your example and the PDF still opens.

In the interest of not posting the entire PDF again, here's how you can update your sample code:

```
.........
/Font <<
>>
/XObject <<
>>

//Start my edit right below this point in your example, so at line 31, add:

/ExtGState << /GS1 10 0 R
>>
>>
endobj
10 0 obj
<<
/Type /ExtGState
/SA true
/TR 11 0 R
>>
endobj
31 0 obj
<< /FunctionType 0
/Domain [0.0 1.0]
/Range [0.0 1.0]
/Size 2
/BitsPerSample 8
/Length 7
/Filter /ASCIIHexDecode
>>
stream
01 00 >
endstream
endobj
// Your code picks back up with:

5 0 obj
<<
/Producer (FPDF 1.6)
```

Basically all I've done is added a dictionary object reference to the main resource dictionary and then created the actual dictionary object with the stroke adjustment rule set to true. I also threw in the transfer function that the spec example has, because i'm not sure if that makes a difference. It can easily be taken out.

Comment: I'm almost positive that the TR is not required here. I've tried it both ways and it doesn't seem to make a difference and I was able to find a working example without it. I've tried the exact same thing as you've suggested in every way imaginable but it's just not working. I'm missing something subtle here and I'll figure it out but I'm getting the feeling it's beyond the scope of this question. I'm marking this sucker as done. THANK YOU for your time/help on this Anthony.

Comment: Hi Travis, this is a bit late, but were you able to work things out? Thanks!